# Extracting a superset from data while preserving parent child relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I have data in SQL which has similar granularity to the following.

```
Person ID    Dish        Restaurant              Cost 
1            Pasta       The Spaghetti House     5
2            Burgers     Burger Factory          7
3            Pasta       The Spaghetti House     5
4            Pizza       The Cheesy Slice        4
```

This is only an example, but it captures the essence of my data and provides a good example. 
I need to abstract from this data a "meal" (a super-set), where a meal consist of a Dish, Restaurant and Cost. I need to  generate a unique "meal" id. The caveat is that I then need to relate a person to a meal.

```
PersonID    MealID        
1            1
2            2
3            1
4            3
```

So far, the best solution I have came up with, is to gerenate a checksum from the dish,restaurant and cost columns. This then lets me uniquely identify each "meal" and also let's me relate each person to each meal by calculating their row's checksum.

I do not even know what this process of extracting a super set of data is called, much less how to do it correctly. (I struggled with the title of this question). I'm not sure using a checksum is the most elegant option although it does seem to work.

Is there a process for extracting super-sets of data while still retaining the relationships between a child (a person) and it's parent (a meal) in SQL?

Comment: Would utilizing more than a single column work towards creating this surrogate "meal" key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is to create a unique number for every unique dish you can use Row_Number with `(select distinct dish)`. Then you just join back on the dish using a CTE.

This guarantees that person ids 2 and 4 will share the same MealID but it doesn't guarantee the order.

```
;with d as (select row_number() over (order by dish) MealID,
        Dish 
        from
        (select distinct dish
        From Data) as t)
Select [person Id],
       MealID
from data
      inner join d
      on data.dish = d.dish
Order by [person id]
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f16e7/9)

If you wanted to do this with restaurants at the same time you just add another cte.

```
;with d as (select row_number() over (order by dish) MealID,
        Dish 
        from
        (select distinct dish
        From Data) as t)
, r as (select row_number() over (order by Restaurant) RestaurantID,
        Restaurant 
        from
        (select distinct Restaurant
        From Data) as t)

Select [person Id],
       MealID,
       RestaurantID
from data
      inner join d
      on data.dish = d.dish
      inner join r
      on data.restaurant = r.Restaurant
Order by [person id]
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f16e7/10)

As an aside if you put these ctes in tables the Output clause in INSERT is your friend. This process is referred to as normalization

Answer (score 1):

I think the following does this:

```
with mealids as (
    select t.*, row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as mealid
    from (select distinct dish, restaurant, cost
          from t
         ) t
)
select t.personid, mealids.mealid 
from t join
     mealids
     on t.dish = mealids.dish and
        t.restaurant = mealids.restaurant and
        t.cost = mealids.cost
```

That is, generate the ids for the combinations in the data.  Then join them back to the original data.

Comment: I like the `order by (select NULL)`